# trouble codes on a 1993 chevy silverado

Tags: chevrolet, dtc, silverado

when I hook my scanner up to view the check engine codes it says I have no power to my scanner. I tested all circuits and my fuses are all good. what could be my problem?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please confirm that you trying to read codes with the ignition in the 'On' position.

Comment: Also confirm you are attempting to utilize an OBD-I scanner and not an OBD-**II** scanner.

Comment: OBD 1 did not provide power to the scan tool. Commonly there is an external cable that hooks to the cigarette liter.

Comment: @vini_i - Hadn't thought of that ... my Innova scanner doesn't require an external power source ... guess it must run off of batteries inside the unit.

Comment: Alternately, you can jump 2 pins on the DLC connector and the CEL will flash the codes.  Instructions here: http://www.chevytalk.org/fusionbb/showtopic.php?tid/273660